# Maven - use -source 5 or higher to enable... while building the project

Tags: maven, java, pom.xml

I downloaded one project from our svn and now I am trying to build this using Maven (mvn clean install... my maven is Apache Maven 3.0.4). Unfortunately, when I try to build, the following error occurs. It is strange that it reports something (I think) about Java version 1.3, which of course I dont have installed in my laptop. I have `JAVA_HOME` setted to JDK 1.7, my javac is also in version 1.7 ...

Please do you know where is the problem?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project irapi: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/jan/nutch/src/plugin/irapi/src/main/java/cz/cvut/fit/linkedtv/irapi/rest/MediaServer.java:[21,1] error: **annotations are not supported in -source 1.3**
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
[ERROR] /home/jan/nutch/src/plugin/irapi/src/main/java/cz/cvut/fit/linkedtv/irapi/solr/SolrQueryResponseConvertor.java:[35,26] error: **for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.3**
```

Comment: Are you running maven from the command line?  In your command line, what does it say when you type `java -version`?

Comment: Yes, from command line. It says jan@jan:~/nutch/src/plugin/irapi$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Weird, well maybe hardcoding the value will fix your issue: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must specify the source configuration parameter to the maven-compiler-plugin like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

See also [Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) in the maven documentation for further details.

Comment: If you get a `(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)` use `<target>1.5</target>` too.